# Image not showing while sharing URL on other platform

Tags: html, facebook, github, meta-tags

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://vickygupta16.github.io/Images/VickyGupta.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="240" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="240" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Display Picture" />
```

I am not able to view the image that should be displayed while sharing URL on social media platform.

I tried different width and height and updated my github repo and still didn't got the image while sharing URL.

I know i am missing a simple step and solution can be very simple, but i am not able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the **[following Facebook recommendations for images](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/)**:

> For high-resolution devices, use images of at least 1,200 x 630
>   pixels. To publish Pages with links with large images, use images with
>   a size of at least 600 x 315 pixels.
>
> We have changed the publication of the Page with links: now the aspect
>   ratio of the images is the same for News Feed on PC and on mobile
>   devices. Try to ensure a 1.91: 1 aspect ratio so that the image in the
>   News Feed is not cropped.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks right to me. The thing is just that not all social media platforms are configured to use OGP (i.e. not all platforms can understand those tags). So there's could be few things:

1. The social media you're trying to use does not support any social meta tags
2. The social media you're trying to use has their own tags (e.g. Twitter)
3. The social media network has cached the content and has not yet updated it after your last modifications

For number 1, there's no solution. For number 2, try to find the tags the platform uses. For number 3, clear the cache and cookies on your browser and try again.

Comment: i tried to share the URL in WhatsApp....the only things getting displayed are title,description and sitename...although i haven't posted the code for same because they displayed correctly. Only Image display is left.